# Meteor cfs standard packages - check Error

Tags: meteor, upload, filesystems

While trying to upload a File to my Database, I am getting a Match Error that is preventing the File to be stored.

Here is the Basic code:

The Initialization:

```
UserImages = new FS.Collection("userImages", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("userImages", {path: "~/uploads"})],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 1048576, //in bytes
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*'],
      extensions: ['png', 'jpg']
    },
    onInvalid: function (message) {
      if (Meteor.isClient) {
        alert(message);
      } else {
        console.log(message);
      }
    }
  }
});

if(Meteor.isServer){

    UserImages.allow({
        insert:function(userId, doc){

          return true;
        },
        update:function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){

          check(doc, Object);

          return true;
        },
        remove:function(){
          return true;
        }
      })
}
```

The Client Code:

```
Template.editProfile.events({
    'change #profileUpload':function(event, template){
        var files = event.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, ln = files.length; i < ln; i++) {

            UserImages.insert(files[i], function (err, fileObj) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Strangly enough, if i run a console.log(typeof file) it gives me back an Object. But when i check the File against an Object with check(file, Object) it gives me this Error:

This is the Stack from the Server:

```
Exception in setTimeout callback: Error: Match error: Expected plain object
     at checkSubtree (packages/check/match.js:279:1)
     at check (packages/check/match.js:32:1)
     at UserImages.allow.update (app/server/allowances.js:91:7)
     at packages/mongo/collection.js:1041:1
     at Array.every (native)
     at Function._.every._.all (packages/underscore/underscore.js:219:1)
     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._validatedUpdate (packages/mongo/collection.js:1038:1)
     at [object Object].m.(anonymous function) (packages/mongo/collection.js:851:1)
     at Object.methods.rateLimit.callFunctionsInQueue (packages/matteodem:easy-security/lib/easy-security.js:72:1)
     at packages/matteodem:easy-security/lib/easy-security.js:116:1
```

Has anyone encountered this problem or has a solution for a workaround? I've tried all kinds of workarounds also with Match.Any but than I get an error telling me that all Arguments have not been run against the check();

I checked the issues in here:
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-base-package/issues
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues

but could not find a solution so far.

Thanks for the help!